# Split clustered data and interpolate by a power function

Tags: r, cluster-computing, analysis

Here is my question:
I have a data frame that looks like this (I have used `Mclust` and some complementary functions to extract the cluster of origin of each couple [KN, DTM]):

```
KN            DTM           CLUST
-20.272190218 -31.0272310     1
-18.933174425 -29.6409366     1
-17.956946728 -28.5448150     1
-17.645953576 -31.0272310     2
-17.150920199 -27.3383515     1
```

In general I have only 2 clusters. I want to regroup all the data belonging to each cluster to a separate data frame in order to calculate the best interpolating function for each cluster. The best interpolating function should be of the type ''power''.

I have used `split` in order to separate data following the cluster of origin but I do not know how to proceed from here. If I understand well the split function create 2 vectors containing the data separated. How can I store this data in a file? Is it possible to apply immediately an interpolating function to the data obtained from split?

Answer (score 2):

The split function returns a **list** of vectors. So, if you store the results of the split function, and then access each element of the list you produced, that is how you can access each result:

`splitData <- split(data, f=data$CLUST)
cluster1 <- splitData[[1]]
cluster2 <- splitData[[2]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also managed to find this solution late in the evening.